# Why is my object created on backend C# becoming null

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm using asp.net and c# for backend code and html, javascript/jquery on frontend

User clicks "Details" on website to view and edit requests previously created.

jquery/ajax  calls method on backend to get infomation about requests.
An object, newWaferRequest, is created which holds this information.  The object is returned from ajax call and the site populates a form with that information.  The user can then edit the form,  add new programs to requests, modify existing requests info etc...

The problem I'm getting is when the user selects "Save pgm", ajax calls backend savePgm method which is supposed to update the Object newWaferRequest previously created, but I'm receiving a nullReferenceException.  The exception is pointing to the newWaferRequest object being null.  This happens at different times when the user is updating the request.  Sometimes the user can update the program and add new programs, with a correct response from backend.  Other times the exception occurs.

I must not have a full grasp of how variables are "stored" when using the web.  I read multiple post on here and have read about  Session and ViewState  variables.  I've tried saving the Object in a Session with no luck.

This is just showing the beginning of my c# code, I tried using static variables initially.  All the objects are in App_code cs files.

```
public partial class Nbump_Request : System.Web.UI.Page
{
//public static person currentPerson = new person();
//public static requestSearch searchRequest;
//public static waferRequest newWaferRequest;
//public static waferRequestObject newWaferRequestObject;

static person currentPerson = new person();
static requestSearch searchRequest;
static waferRequest newWaferRequest;
static waferRequestObject newWaferRequestObject;
```

Here is ajax method for existing requests, which creates objects

```
[WebMethod]
public static string queryRequestExisting(string request_pk)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {
        newWaferRequest = new waferRequest(request_pk, "EXISTINGREQUEST");
        newWaferRequestObject = newWaferRequest.CURRENTREQUEST;
        string json = js.Serialize(newWaferRequest);
        return json;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }　
}
```

Here is ajax code for when user saves or updates program information. I added in the code to check and return with the object was null.

```
public static string savePgmData(Dictionary<string, string> pgm_requests)
{
    PgmRequestObject currentPgm;
    if (newWaferRequest != null)
    {
        try
        {
            //if (!Convert.ToBoolean(pgm_requests["pgmEdit"])) //not performed when request pgm being edited
             string rtnMessage;
            //create new pgm in waferRequest object
            if (pgm_requests["PGMRT_INDEX_PK"] == null)
            {
                int index = newWaferRequest.addNewPGMRequest() - 1;
                currentPgm = (PgmRequestObject)newWaferRequest.PGMREQUESTLIST[index];
                string pgmPrimaryKey = currentPgm.PGMRT_INDEX_PK;
                rtnMessage = "{\"message\": \"Added and saved new pgm successfully\", \"primaryKey\":\"" + pgmPrimaryKey + "\"}";
            }
            //get pgm to update at index provided
            else if (pgm_requests["pgmRowIndex"] != "-1")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(pgm_requests["pgmRowIndex"]);
                currentPgm = (PgmRequestObject)newWaferRequest.PGMREQUESTLIST[index];
                rtnMessage = "Edited and saved pgm successfully";
            }
            //save initial pgm
            else
            {
               currentPgm = (PgmRequestObject)newWaferRequest.PGMREQUESTLIST[0];
               rtnMessage = "Initial pgm added successfully";
            }
　
　
            currentPgm.updatePGM(pgm_requests["pgmNameList"], pgm_requests["pgmNameText"]);
            currentPgm.updateStatus(pgm_requests["pgmStatus"]);
            currentPgm.updateWafers(pgm_requests["pgmWfrList"], pgm_requests["pgmWfrNum"]);
            currentPgm.updatePriority(pgm_requests["pgmTestOrder"]);
            currentPgm.updateFailBinRetest(pgm_requests["pgmFbr"], pgm_requests["pgmFbrBins"]);
            //currentPgm.CommitIntoDatabase(); // -- Called on individual requests updates before request saved
　
            return rtnMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Failed to save program\n\n" + ex.Data + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "newWaferRequest object is null\n";
    }
}
```

This is a short snippet of the class for waferRequest. This is located in the app_code and is a cs file.  The pgmRequestList contains an array of pgm objects.  That is what I update when user selects "Save Program".

```
public class waferRequest
{
    /*The class will hold request information, creation and delete.
     *
     */
    private waferRequestObject currentRequest;
    private ArrayList WaferRequestList = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList PGMRequestList = new ArrayList();
```

Here is an example of what I tried for Session.  I got rid of static variables and modified the methods

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static string queryRequestExisting(string request_pk)
{
    waferRequest newWaferRequest;
    waferRequestObject newWaferRequestObject;

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {
        newWaferRequest = new waferRequest(request_pk, "EXISTINGREQUEST");
        newWaferRequestObject = newWaferRequest.CURRENTREQUEST;

        HttpContext.Current.Session["newWaferRequest"] = newWaferRequest;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["newWaferRequestObject"] = newWaferRequestObject;

        string json = js.Serialize(newWaferRequest);
        return json;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }　
}


//snippet of savePgmData with session 
public static string savePgmData(Dictionary<string, string> pgm_requests)
{
    waferRequest newWaferRequest = HttpContext.Current.Session["newWaferRequest"];

    PgmRequestObject currentPgm;
    if (newWaferRequest != null)
    {
        try
        {
            //if (!Convert.ToBoolean(pgm_requests["pgmEdit"])) //not performed when request pgm being edited
             string rtnMessage;
            //create new pgm in waferRequest object
            if (pgm_requests["PGMRT_INDEX_PK"] == null)
            {
                int index = newWaferRequest.addNewPGMRequest() - 1;
                currentPgm = (PgmRequestObject)newWaferRequest.PGMREQUESTLIST[index];
```

I am limited to the code I'm allowed to show because of work security. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Also, the code seems to work fine on my local server.  The issue is when I put it on the production server or development server  --  Both of which I don't have access to make changes on.

Comment: Are you using Web Garden's in your Application Pool that is used for your web site on the production server?  If so that could be the issue.

Comment: I'm fairly new to web development of any kind.  I'm not sure how the production server is set up.   I'll have to ask my  IT department how they set it up.   I was hoping it was just something in my code...  Or maybe in the web.config file that I need to apply.

Comment: It is virtually impossible to understand what your issue is and posting a bunch of incomplete code just obfuscates the issue even further, for instance you have 2 different queryRequestExisting method definition.

Please just show us where you are getting the null Reference exception.
This is a fairly common error that usually indicates some problem in your code like a failed Database update possibly due to a missing parameter etc.
You should point breakpoints and see exactly where the error occurs

Comment: Yes, I realize it is hard to understand what the problem is... Trust me, I've read a lot of different forum questions and answers.  It you notice on the two different queryExistingData methods... One was my original code and the second was showing how I was trying to use Session to store the object.  The problem occurs when I try to to call savePgmData where I have the code   if ( newWaferRequest != null ) - - sometimes it is null sometimes it's not null.